# pgfplots trim to axis area even with extra ticklabels

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, margins

I have a plot with extra x tick labels on top in `pgfplots` that i wish to display in a figure at the top of my page.

I wish to have the top of the actual axis rectangle directly at the top, with the extra tick label protruding into the top margin. Since i am using `tikz-externalize` i dont think a simple \vskip will work, plus since not all the ticklabels have the same length, id prefer something universal.

ideally there would be something like the `[trim axis left]` setting just with `[trim axis top]`.

is there some way to implement something similar?

example with margins shown: (https://www.writelatex.com/186618fknbff)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
extra x ticks={60},
extra x tick labels ={\rotatebox{90}{ESB}},
extra x tick style  = { tick pos=right, grid=major, ticklabel pos=right},
xlabel=testlabel,
scale only axis,
width=\textwidth,
height=5cm
]
\addplot coordinates {
(0.1, 4)
(0.5, 2.5)
(1, 7.5)
(2, 2.6)
(3, 5.6)
(7, 1.4)
(17, 4.3)
(40, 1.4)
(92, 3.3)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{testcaption}
\end{figure}
%
%
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
extra x ticks={60},
extra x tick labels ={\rotatebox{90}{ESBaaaaaa}},
extra x tick style  = { tick pos=right, grid=major, ticklabel pos=right},
xlabel=testlabel,
scale only axis,
width=\textwidth,
height=5cm
]
\addplot coordinates {
(0.1, 4)
(0.5, 2.5)
(1, 7.5)
(2, 2.6)
(3, 5.6)
(7, 1.4)
(17, 4.3)
(40, 1.4)
(92, 3.3)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{testcaption}
\end{figure}
%
\Blindtext
%
\end{document}
```

(there seems to be some bug as well that shifts the x axis label down as if the extra tick label were at the bottom but that is easily corrected by an xlabel shift for now)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of this site.

Comment: You can use `every extra x tick/.append style={overlay}` such that the extra tick labels are not included in the bounding box computation.

Comment: this does what i had in mind. thanks! is there a way to mark this as answered?

Comment: @percusse: This doesn't work if the picture is externalised, though...

Comment: @Jake Oh, I've completely overlooked the externalisation part. Right.

Comment: @Jake i realized that just after comenting -_-


turns out the [trim axis left] stuff is done via some extra commands in the .dpth file which dont allow for easy modification for trimming the top.


Im just doing an \vspace just before including the tikz file now. that works for now and i realized i dont have that many different tick lable lengths so i dont have to adjust the amount of shift often

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the baseline option.

`\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline]`

Comment: Welcome! I think you could be right. Nevertheless, can you add some details, why and how this works and about the difference using the option or leaving it?